# XAML error when using Localized Resources in Context Menu

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I have the following code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FavList">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="PlayPause" Style="{StaticResource IconButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,2,0,2" Width="72" Click="PlayPause_Click" BorderThickness="0">
                <ImageBrush x:Name="PlayPauseImage" ImageSource="Assets\Images\Play.png" />
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="myStreamName" Margin="84,8,8,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='Test'}" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="myStreamDescription" Margin="84,37,8,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding About, FallbackValue='Testing'}" FontSize="16"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="myStreamURL" Text="{Binding URL}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="DeleteFavorite" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.DeleteFavButton, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"  Click="DeleteFavorite_Click" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I have the MenuItem Header equal to what I have there now, I keep getting invalid XAML errors.  When I just put in header="Delete" Everything is fine.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: More detail on the XAML error, please?
The XAML looks correct syntax-wise, and doesn't generate any error when I paste it into a project page.
So, any chance DeleteFavButton is not defined in LocalizedResources?

Comment: I wish I had more info, Visual Studio highlights everything between and including <DataTemplate> and says XAML error on the line with the menu item.  I take out the binding, and just put in text. everything is fine.  Cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: I love XAML!  I don't see a problem with the declaration of the binding, but I am no XAML expert.  You might try making changes elsewhere within the <DataTemplate> to see if those also toggle between error and no error (which I bet will be true).  You might also try changing the MenuItem.Header definition to the static resource at runtime to work around the issue.